# PHP upload file jquery

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Ive got contact form with PHP and jquery.
Everything works fine except the upload file. its not uploaded to the folder.
if i put the PHP code in the same page as html page, the upload file works fine?

HTML:

```
<form id="vacancy" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Full name</label><input type="text" id="fullname">
<label>Please upload your cv</label><input name="uploadcv" type="file" id="uploadcv">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Application" id="submit">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#vacancy").submit(function() {           
   $.post ( "include/vacancy.php", {
       fullname: $("#fullname").val(), 
       uploadcv: $("#uploadcv").val()},
function(data){ });
```

PHP:

```
  $name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['uploadcv']['name']);
  $type_of_uploaded_file = 
        substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
        strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploadcv"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

    $max_allowed_file_size = 100; // size in KB 
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf');
    $upload_folder = 'cv/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
    $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
    $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploadcv"]["tmp_name"];
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)) {
      if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))  {
        echo  '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you'd like us to close this for you, flag it specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think you can upload files like that using jquery. However, it seems you can use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#sample7) to upload files but I haven´t tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cv folder is in your root directory:

```
$name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['uploadcv']['name']);
$type_of_uploaded_file = 
substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

$size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploadcv"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

$max_allowed_file_size = 100; // size in KB 
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf');
**$upload_folder = './cv/';** //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
$path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
$tmp_path = $_FILES["uploadcv"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)) {
  if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))  {
    echo  '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
  }
}
```